# Crontab -e will ignore my edits

Tags: apache, ssh, cron

Via SSH, i type: `crontab -e`

Then the GNU nano editor opens the document, I've tried this different contents for the file:

```
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55    *    *    *    *    /usr/bin/lynx -source http://mywebsite.com/includes/boot.php
```

--

```
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55    *    *    *    *    http://mywebsite.com/includes/boot.php
```

--

```
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55    *    *    *    *    home/myuser/includes/boot.php
```

After saving the file i get:

> 7953401631:~# crontab -e
>   crontab: installing new crontab
>   You have new mail in /var/mail/root

But none of them seems to work

What am i missing? BTW I am running under CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an interpreter. Hence you need something like

```
15 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/script
```

Also check your system log if cron is running at all. Try

```
which php
```

to get current php and path

Comment: Thanks! how can I know my /path/to/php-cgi ?

Comment: Maybe you need `php-cli`, try run `which php` to find where php command line is .

Comment: I don't know. I compile it myself and it's in binary folder of php sourcecode. You can be lucky with /usr/bin or try find?

Comment: It returned /user/bin/php tested your syntax and worked, thanks!

Comment: Did you use php-cli or php syntax in crontab?

Comment: Nevermind. I also have php not php-cli.

Comment: @Clippit: BTW. there doesn't exist php-cli only php with cli support. You can test it when you run php -v. When you compile it with cli support it's in sapi/cli folder.